# Mapping user defined types in entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

We would like to use a user-defined type and have that type mapped separately in Entity Framework.

The type is defined in SQL Server as:

```
CREATE TYPE EncryptedSSN FROM VARCHAR(MAX) NULL ;
```

And this type is intended to store encrypted data, so we want to have the column type appear when used in code. Instead of the type being `EncryptedSSN`, the type is `Varchar(max)`.

We use handlers for columns based on the data type. Since Entity Framework does not support encrypted columns, we would like to encrypt certain fields and handle the encryption invisibly to the rest of the code. There are other columns defined as varchar(max), so it is not possible to filter them by that criteria.

We understand that Entity Framework does not support user defined types in CLR. If this is incorrect, please let me know otherwise.

How can we get the type `EncryptedSSN` to appear in the model browser?

Answer (score -1):

This is crude, but you could make the column  `varchar(some_number_which_is_unlikely_to_be_used_for_another_purpose)`